# Что этот дефайн возвращает? Что это за запись?

Tags: c

```
#define QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT(x) \
    struct { \
        int:(x) ? -1 : 1; \
    }
```

Я понимаю что в принципе этот код делает, конкрето ARRAY_SIZE. Но вот этот дефайн выше меня сводит сума

Вот весь стек дефайнов

```
#define QEMU_IS_ARRAY(x) (!__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), \
                                                        typeof(&(x)[0])))
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) ((sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0])) + \
                       QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(!QEMU_IS_ARRAY(x)))
#define QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT(x) \
    struct { \
        int:(x) ? -1 : 1; \
    }
#define QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(x) (sizeof(QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT(x)) - \
                                   sizeof(QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT(x)))
```

QEMU_IS_ARRAY возвращает либо 1 либо 0, так ? 1 - значит массив, 0 не массив(В случае если типы не совпадают) QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT(x) для меня загадка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Это очень сильное колдунство... (c) какой-то опер

#### Что это делает

- `QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON`, согласно имени, должен вызывать ошибку компиляции, если ей передано истинной значение.
- `QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` — аналогично, но также она должна предстовлять собой выражение с нулевым значением, т.е. по факту это `static_assert`, возвращающий `0`.
- `QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT` — просто служебный макрос с помощью которого и реализован `QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO`

#### Как это работает

`QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT` раскрывается в определение анонимной структуры с безымянным битовым полем:

```
struct {
    int:(x) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Или если добавить имена:

```
struct foo {
    int bar:(x) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Если значение выражения `x` равно `0`, то битовое поле определяется со значением `1` и структура является корректно объявленной.

В противном случае структура оказывается определённой с битовым полем отрицательной длины (`-1`), что вызывает ошибку.

`QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(x)` — это просто выражение с нулевым значением (`n-n`); если `n` корректно (`x` истинно и определение структуры в `QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT` не вызывает ошибку компиляции), то это равносильно следующему:

```
sizeof(struct {int :1;}) - sizeof(struct {int :1;})
```

В противном случае оно, само собой, просто вызывает ошибку компиляции.

Так изощряться пришлось, чтобы впихнуть проверку времени компиляции прямо в определение `ARRAY_SIZE` и оно ничего не испортило.

Comment: А вообще есть вариант обратиться к анонимной переменной внутри этой структуры ?

Comment: @АндрейПетров, нет... да и данная структура вообще не предназначена для создания... только битовое поле не *анонимное* (*anonymous*), а *безымянное* (*unnamed*)... Обычно они используются для отступов, чтобы другие битовые поля были корректно выравнены.

Answer (score 1):

При определении размера массива обычным способом `sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0])` крайне легко прострелить себе ногу, когда `x` не является массивом, а является указателем. Соответственно `QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT` работает по аналогии со `static_assert` - если срабатывает условие `!QEMU_IS_ARRAY(x)`, то будет объявлена структура с битовым полем меньше нуля, что вызовет ошибку времени компиляции.

```
int * not_arr = NULL;
size_t size = QARRAY_SIZE(not_arr); // error
```

Answer (score -1):

в C `if(x)` означает: `x!=0`

```
x != 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

`QEMU_BUILD_BUG_ON_STRUCT(1)` вернёт структуру с переменной `int`,

```
{
 int: -1; //-1 - если x != 0 и 1 если x == 0
}
```

Comment: Так а что это за переменная такая без имени? Когда такое может пригодится и почему именно структура, вам не ясно? Нельзя ли просто вернуть int

Comment: ну структуры без имени обычно возвращаются из функций, а далее с ними можно работать, или вы не про это?

Comment: Ну структуры без имени я знаю, мне интересно, как обратиться к переменной без имени внутри этой структуры, зачем она нужна. Неужели только по памяти прыгать

Comment: а, у неё имя int, это не тип

Comment: В смысле имя, а тип тогда какой:)?

Comment: int :) типо int: int